# Python selenium doesn't click the button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Can you tell me why at this website: https://pasja-informatyki.pl/programowanie-webowe/test/przeglad-html/
I have no idea why it's not clicking the button. Maybe the alert after clicking is messing with selenium?
I tried differend selectors and didn't work. I hope someone can help me :D

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os

class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.action = ActionChains(self.driver)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.get("https://pasja-informatyki.pl/programowanie-webowe/test/przeglad-html/")
        sleep(1)
        x = 1
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("hcks").click()
        for x in range (10):
            #pytanie = self.driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(f"{x+1}.").text
            pytanie = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//div[contains(text(),'{x+1}.')]").text
            f = open("pio.txt", "a")
            f.write(pytanie + "\n")
            f.close()

            self.driver.find_element_by_id(f"odpa{x+1}").click();
            self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 500)")

        self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 3500)")
        sleep(1)
        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-large#sprawdz"))))
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='przycisk']").click()

        #self.action.move_to_element(przycisk).click(sprawdz).perform()
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='sprawdz']").click();
        #self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("ok").click();
        for x in range (10):
            odpowiedz = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//div[contains(text(),'odp{x+1}') and @class='odpgood']").text
            f = open("pio.txt", "a")
            f.write(odpowiedz + "\n")
            f.close()


Bot()
```

Comment: You do have a semicolon oddly in several areas.

Comment: thanks, i deleted them, but it seems they didn't cause any problem

Answer (score 2):

To click on <kbd>Rozumiem</kbd> you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `id`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_id("hcks").click()
  ```
- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span#hcks").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='hcks']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `ID`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "hcks"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span#hcks"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='hcks']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: it's not clicking this damn button xD wtih id @id='sprawdz'. So annoying xD

Comment: can you run this code and see why it's not working?

Comment: @MikołajK using `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "hcks"))).click()` will uliminate the need of the sleep's

Comment: ye but the previous button with id sprawdz creates problem

Answer (score 0):

Your **`actions.perform()`**  section is commented. Ensure you call the perform() method to Performs all stored actions.

```
#self.action.move_to_element(przycisk).click(sprawdz).perform()
```

If this does not work can you try without ActionChains?

Following worked and button was closed.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://pasja-informatyki.pl/programowanie-webowe/test/przeglad-html/")
assert "Test wiedzy - 10 pytań" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("hcks")
elem.click()
```

Comment: it's commented because it didn't work :/ I have no clue why this specific button can't be clicked

Comment: Sample code can be found https://github.com/pragmatictesters/Pragmatic-Learning-SeleniumWebDriver-B01D2020/tree/master/src/test/java/com/pragmatic/examples/selenium/stackoverflow. Can you give a try without ActionChains?

Comment: BTW I started with Python + Selenium. You code worked successfully. I ran the code on Mac 10.15.7 (19H15) Catalina, Python 3.7.6 https://www.screencast.com/t/riqZTyzzsA